# Django site won't load both http and https links submitted via form/model

Tags: python, html, django

Users can submit links to external sites via a form and "Event Website" field on my site. The site is sent to the "link" model in the admin and is rendered in the template with `<a href="//{{ item.link }}" target="_blank"> {{ item.title }} </a>`.

However, not all links are loading the external site.

When on the production site, only links with "https://" included that are actually secure navigate to the external site.

Links entered without "https://" that are not secure such as "http://www.notsecuresite.com", "notsecuresite.com" or "www.notsecuresite.com" do not load. I get "This site can't be reached" and my site adds "https://http//" to the link when clicking on it and attempting to load it.

How can I get my page to load the external site no matter how the link is entered (given that it's valid)?

Comment: have u tried removing the // and let just the {{ item.link }}

Comment: @rubico yes. If I do that, then any site that includes https:// or http:// does not load. If they do not include https:// or http:// they do load secure or not.